# Spring-boot wiremockserver stub junit tests not running

Tags: spring-boot, testing, junit, wiremock

I am trying to make mockserver tests using wiremock for my spring api.

I am just learning about it as I go.

I made a test to test a post request but it wont run.

Here is the test

```
public class TrackControllerWireMockServerTest {

    private WireMockServer wireMockServer;
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        wireMockServer = new WireMockServer();
        wireMockServer.start();

        configureFor("localhost", wireMockServer.port());

        stubFor(post(urlPathEqualTo("/codechallenge/createTrack"))
                .withQueryParam("isrc", equalTo("TEST_ISRC"))
                .withRequestBody(equalToJson("{\"name\":\"test_name\",\"durationMs\":1000,\"explicit\":true}"))
                .willReturn(aResponse()
                        .withStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value())
                        .withHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .withBody("{\"isrc\":\"TEST_ISRC\",\"name\":\"test_name\",\"durationMs\":1000,\"explicit\":true}")));

        restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        wireMockServer.stop();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCreateTrack() {
        TrackMetadata metadata = new TrackMetadata(1000L, "test_name", true);
        ResponseEntity<Track> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(
                "http://localhost:" + wireMockServer.port() + "/codechallenge/createTrack?isrc=TEST_ISRC",
                metadata, Track.class);

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, responseEntity.getStatusCode());
        assertEquals("TEST_ISRC", responseEntity.getBody().getIsrc());
        assertEquals("test_name", responseEntity.getBody().getName());
        assertEquals(1000L, (long) responseEntity.getBody().getDurationMs());
        assertEquals(true, responseEntity.getBody().isExplicit());
    } }
```

there is no errors, failures or stack trace, the test just doesnt run.

I right click project and select run as JUnit test

Comment: Try different versions junit or jupiter. And if it`s not help check all your dependencies required for wiremock.

Comment: Please show the imports and your build file (e.g. `pom.xml` if you are using Maven).